# Please fix your application to end transactions in progress properly and to close the database when it is no longer needed

Tags: firebase

Trying to integrate FireBase to my app for Push Notifications. I have followed all the instructions given by FirreBase Console. But my app crash when I run it for the first time. Here is LOG.

> 04-03 13:16:38.620 1514-1525/? W/SQLiteConnectionPool: A SQLiteConnection object for database '/data/user/0/com.google.android.gms/databases/metrics.db' was leaked!  Please fix your application to end transactions in progress properly and to close the database when it is no longer needed.
>       04-03 13:16:38.622 1514-1525/? W/SQLiteConnectionPool: A SQLiteConnection object for database '/data/user/0/com.google.android.gms/databases/help_responses.db.18' was leaked!  Please fix your application to end transactions in progress properly and to close the database when it is no longer needed.
>       04-03 13:16:38.623 1514-1525/? W/SQLiteConnectionPool: A SQLiteConnection object for database '/data/user/0/com.google.android.gms/databases/auto_complete_suggestions.db' was leaked!  Please fix your application to end transactions in progress properly and to close the database when it is no longer needed.

Here is my app gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {

    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.1"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 20
        versionName "2.0.8"

        ndk {
            moduleName = "cTunesInit"
        }
    }

    buildTypes {

    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            jniLibs.srcDir 'jniLibs'
        }
    }

    repositories {
        mavenCentral() // jcenter() works as well because it pulls from Maven Central
    }

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

    //pallette
    compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:25.1.1'

    //appcompat
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.1'

    //design
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.1'

    //volley
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0'

    //paypal
    compile 'com.paypal.sdk:paypal-android-sdk:2.13.1'

    // CardView
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.1.1'

    // RecyclerView
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.1.1'

    //glide
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'

    //FireBase Analytics and Push Notifications
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.0'
}

// FireBase
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I have updated libraries. But still not working. I don't know what went wrong.

Comment: I didn't add any code yet. As i said, this is my first run.

Comment: But here my problem is different. i have just created new project in Firebase console, Added json file to my project, added libraries to gradle files. that's it and run the app. it crashes.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with my Android Device, i don't know what it is exactly. I have tried many times but not recovered from the crash problem. But when i run it on another device it's working.